# Why is the bounty of 50 not available on a question?

Tags: support, bounty

I was trying to offer a 50-rep bounty on this question:

[How many Jedi (Knights) lived in the galaxy before The Clone Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/how-many-jedi-knights-lived-in-the-galaxy-before-the-clone-wars/10315#10315)

And the bounty pop-up's smallest bounty value was 100.

Why wasn't 50 rep available for the bounty value?

As an experiment, I picked another random question from 2 days ago and that one DID have a value of 50 in the pop-up, so it's not specific to my account, just to that question.

Comment: There you go, now there's a 50 rep bounty on it. :)

Comment: @Keen - thanks! I hope a full answer will be found! This seems like such a bloody obvious data point that it HAD to have been covered in the gazillion EU sources.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you've answered a question, you can't set a 50-point bounty on it. See [Undocumented increase in minimum bounty value?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116476/undocumented-increase-in-minimum-bounty-value/116477#116477) on the main meta. The reason is that your bounty will drive traffic to your answer, and [the SE developers consider this abusive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639) (I personally disagree with this assessment).

Comment: Thanks! +1. ... We are cosmically bound to disagree. I actually happen to fully agree with SE developers on this - on intuitive basis, thus I'd gladly change my mind if some statistics is available.